# Updating incoming list with existing data using operators

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, operators

I've 2 lists

1. Updated list coming from the server.
2. A locally stored copy of the list that came from the server

The incoming server list data will replace the data in the localList however before doing that I need to merge data from localList into the incomingList because some items in the local list could have been modified.

I'm doing it the following way which looks Java like because of loops. Is there a Kotlin way of doing it?

```
val localList = List<Animal> ...
fun onIncomingData(incomingList : List<Animal>) {

    val mutableList = incomingList.toMutableList()
    
    mutableList.forEachIndex{ index, freshItem ->
       localList.forEach { localItem ->
          if(localItem is Cat && localItem.id == freshItem.id) {
             mutableList[index] = freshItem.copy(value1 = localItem.value1, value2 = localItem.value2)
            return@forEach
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn operators but I usually struggle to figure out if there's a way to achieve something with kotlin collection operators that I'm doing with loops. Hence the question

Comment: You say you want the incoming list data to replace the local data - so why are you copying local data to the incoming data? Just delete the relevant item from the incoming list that you don't want to replace the local list with.

Comment: @k314159 The data coming from the server is updated data however there's some local data in the model objects that needs to be copied over to items with matching ids of the incoming list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the inner forEach loop, use:

```
localList.find {it is Cat && it.id == freshItem.id}?.let {
    mutableList[index] = freshItem.copy(value1 = it.value1, value2 = it.value2)
}
```

Also, I assume your real code will do something with the mutable list you've created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't have access to the `Cat` type in the let block.

Comment: @user2498079 you can always cast it. I assume you mean that value1 and value2 are Cat specific. then you could do `(it as Cat).value1` and `(it as Cat).value2`

Comment: Yes that's true. I'm trying to learn if there's another way to get the actual type in let block since we're checking for `Cat` type in the `find` block

Comment: @user2498079 perhaps try `localList.find {it is Cat && it.id == freshItem.id} as? Cat?.let ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing elements in a mutable list you could just map over the incoming list and keep some elements while replacing others, like this:

```
val resultList = incomingList.map{ freshItem ->
    val existing = localList.find { it is Cat && it.id == freshItem.id } as Cat?
    if(existing != null) freshItem.copy(value1 = existing.value1, value2 = existing.value2) else freshItem
}
```